# What is a NULL XML file?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I want to make a NULL XML file. I have come up with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<open>
</open>
```

Is this considered a NULL XML file? Or is it just an empty file with .xml extension.

Comment: What is a *NULL XML file*, and why do you think you need to create one? AFAIK, there is no such thing, and no reason that anyone would ever need such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** A "*NULL XML file*" is neither conventional nor standard terminology but likely refers to a minimal XML document, a single empty element, in a file.

**Longer explanation:** Your example XML has

1. an XML declaration,
2. an `open` element,
3. a text node child of the `open` element consisting of a newline character.

An *XML document*, which is standard terminology, must have at least a document element – an empty file is not a well-formed XML document.

An *XML parsed entity*, which also is standard terminology, may minimally be an empty file.

So:

- A file consisting of an empty element, `<e/>`, is a *minimal XML document*.
- An empty file is a *minimal XML parsed entity*.

Given that user-level tools and conversations regarding "XML files" most frequently are about files containing XML documents, someone asking for a "*NULL XML file*" likely wants a file containing a minimal XML document:  `<e/>`.

---

<sub>Thanks to Michael Kay for the helpful suggestion to consider *XML parsed entities* in addition to *XML documents*.</sub>

Comment: I guess that's the minimal XML document. But an empty file is a minimal XML parsed entity, so if we're being pedantic, I guess an empty file is an XML file - it just isn't a NULL XML file, whatever that might be!!

Comment: @MichaelKay: Good point.   Added XML parsed entity vs XML document differentiation to answer.  Thank you!